# Count when 2 columns are empty on QlikSense

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I need some help to count the number of line empty in 2 columns on QlikSense formula.

In the example, when the column "Item" is filled, I would like to count the number of lines which have both "Info 1" and "Info 2" empty.

In this case it should be 2 (Line B and Line E).

[image: Table for counting]

Does anybody know how to do this formula?

Many thanks,

Wil

Answer (score -1):

I found this post with the [solution](https://community.qlik.com/t5/New-to-Qlik-Sense/Count-when-2-columns-are-empty/m-p/1994450#M216615).